# Function to split strings using string::find and string::substr returns wrong tokens

Tags: c++, string

```
//splits a string into a vector of multiple tokens
std::vector<string> split_str(std::string& str, const char* delimiter){
    std::vector<string> ret;
    size_t currPos = 0;
    //Add the first element to the vector
    if (str.find(delimiter) != string::npos)
        ret.push_back(str.substr(currPos, str.find(delimiter)));


    while (currPos != str.size() - 1){

        if (str.find(delimiter, currPos) != string::npos){
            //Current at one past the delimiter
            currPos = str.find(delimiter, currPos) + 1;
            //Substring everything from one past the delimiter until the next delimiter
            ret.push_back(str.substr(currPos, str.find(delimiter, currPos)));
        }
        //If last whitespace is not right at the end
        else if (currPos < str.size()){
            //Add the last element to the vector and end the loop
            ret.push_back(str.substr(currPos, str.size()));
            currPos = str.size() - 1;
        }

    }
    return ret;
}
```

The program is supposed to take a string and a delimiter as an input and return a vector of strings (tokens) as an output. However, when I try it with a simple input such as:

ab bc cd de (delimiter is " ")

The output will be 5 elements: "ab", "bc cd", "cd de", "de", "de"

Comment: There should be a lot of duplicates regarding this problem. You may fix you logic errors by sketching the algorithm on paper.

Comment: @DieterLücking I already did this. I seem to have forgotten that the second parameter of substr is count, not end position. Solving that seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that second parameter to `std::string::substr()` is count not position. Your code should be modified from:

```
if (str.find(delimiter) != string::npos)
    ret.push_back(str.substr(currPos, str.find(delimiter)));
```

to this:

```
auto fpos = str.find(delimiter);
if (fpos != string::npos)
    ret.push_back(str.substr(currPos, fpos - currPos));
    //                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and so on.

Comment: To add to this answer, the first time you push back a token into your return vector, `currPos` is `0`, obviating the need to use `str.find(delimiter) - currPos`. You should, however, not separate the first instance of finding the delimiter with any of the others -- this should all happen within the same loop, using the same positioning logic.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more correct to use `find_first_of` instead of `find`. Take into account that there can be adjacent blanks in the string and moreover the string can start from a blank.

Here is a demonstrative porgram that shows how the function can be written

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split_str( const std::string &s, const char *delimiter )
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0;
          ( pos = s.find_first_not_of( delimiter, pos ) ) != std::string::npos;
          pos = s.find_first_of( delimiter, pos ) )
    {
        ++n;
    }        

    v.reserve( n );

    for ( std::string::size_type pos = 0;
          ( pos = s.find_first_not_of( delimiter, pos ) ) != std::string::npos; )
    {
        auto next_pos = s.find_first_of( delimiter, pos );

        if ( next_pos == std::string::npos ) next_pos = s.size();

        v.push_back( s.substr( pos, next_pos - pos ) );

        pos = next_pos;
    }        

    return v;
}


int main() 
{
    std::string s( "ab bc cd de " );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;    

    auto v = split_str( s, " " );

    for ( auto t : v ) std::cout << t << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ab bc cd de 
ab
bc
cd
de
```